# How to print only 1 line from database to C++

Tags: c++, mysql, dev-c++

for my program I have few lines of questions stored in my database [image: database].

I want my program to display 1 line at a time. For now my output prints out all the lines at the same time.

[image: example].

I don't know what should be the code to print out only one particular line.

```
void quiz()
{
    int difficulty;
    
    system("cls");
    cout<<"Choose your difficulty\n 1. EASY || 2. MEDIUM || 3. HARD\n";
    cin>>difficulty;
    
    if(difficulty==1)
    {
        MYSQL_ROW row;
        MYSQL_RES* res;
        int i=0;
        
        cout<<"You have choosen EASY DIFFICULTY questions";
        system("cls");

        int qstate=mysql_query(obj, "SELECT * FROM questions");
        if(!qstate)
        {
            res = mysql_store_result(obj);
            while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                cout<<"Question no : "<<i+1<<endl;
                cout<<row[1]<<endl;
            
                
            }
                    
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Failed to fetch";
        }   
            
    }
    else if(difficulty==2)
    {
        cout<<"You have choosen MEDIUM DIFFICULTY questions";
    }
    else if(difficulty==3)
    {
        cout<<"You have choosen HARD DIFFICULTY questions";
    }
    else
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Wrong Choice Select Again!!!\n";
        quiz();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well...not by doing this: `fflush(stdin);`. That invokes *undefined behavior*. Whatever resource (be it human, electronic, or otherwise), suggested that, elevate your suspicions of their subject expertise, because that's flat-wrong.  Outside of `cin>>difficulty;` I don't see anywhere in the posted code where the user is prompted for any input, nor any input read, so naturally this isn't going to 'pause' for anything.

Answer (score 1):

You explicitly told it to iterate over all the returned database rows and print them with this code:

```
            while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))
            {
                fflush(stdin);
                cout<<"Question no : "<<i+1<<endl;
                cout<<row[1]<<endl;
            
                
            }
```

Ignoring the `flush(stdin)`, which you don't want, this loop says "As long as there is data to fetch, print it."

Also the `<<i+1` part is not incrementing `i`, it is just adding one to zero then printing that which is why all your lines say "Question 1".

Comment: Do you what code should i replace with `cout<<row[1]<<endl;` So that my program would only print only one particular line ?

Comment: The problem is not with the `cout` statement, it's the `while(row = mysql_fetch_row(res))` that is fetching each row in turn. You're getting multiple rows because your `SELECT * FROM questions`  query told the database to return _all_ the rows from that table. You need to determine whether you intended to read all the rows, or whether you intended to loop over each read row and print it. I can't determine that.